# lsof versus /proc/$PID/fd versus ulimit -n

Tags: proc, file-descriptors, lsof

I am trying to find the reason why my long-running app sometimes busts the maximum open file descriptor limit (`ulimit -n`). I would like to periodically log how many file descriptors the app has open so that I can see when the spike occurred.

I know that `lsof` includes a bunch of items that are excluded from `/proc/$PID/fd`... Are those items relevant with regard to the open file descriptor limit? I.e. should I be logging info from `lsof` or from `/proc/$PID/fd`?

Comment: IMO they are open files...good questions nonetheless. Btw, depending on the server, it maybe be faster following the global number of open files `sysctl fs.file-nr | awk ' { print $3 } '`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr `ls -U /proc/PID/fd | wc -l` will tell you the number that should be less than `ulimit -n`.

`/proc/PID/fd` should contain all the file descriptors opened by a process, including but not limited to strange ones like `epoll` or `inotify` handles, "opaque" directory handles opened with `O_PATH`, handles opened with `signalfd()` or `memfd_create()`, sockets returned by `accept()`, etc.

I'm not a great `lsof` user, but `lsof` is getting its info from `/proc`, too. I don't think there's another way to get the list of the file descriptors a process has opened on Linux other than `procfs`, or by attaching to a process with `ptrace`.

Anyways, the current and root directory, mmapped files (including its own binary and dynamic libraries) and controlling terminal of a process are not counted against the limit set with `ulimit -n` (`RLIMIT_NOFILE`), and they also don't appear in `/proc/PID/fd` unless the process is explicitly holding open handles to them.